# How to invoke the "Organize imports" TypeScript feature in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

There is a new feature in TypeScript 2.8 that lets you "**Organize imports**":
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-8-2/#organize-imports

Basically it does the following:

- remove unnecessary import statements
- sort the import statements

The page shows that the feature can be invoked in Visual Studio Code with the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> keyboard shortcut. Does anybody know how this feature can be invoked in Visual Studio (2017)?

**UPDATE:**

From version **15.8** onward Visual Studio 2017 highlights unused imports by greying them out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This feature has now been added to Visual Studio 2017.

One can invoke it the following ways:

1. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
2. Right-click in the code window and click `Organize Imports` in the context menu.

Answer (score 72):

Visual Studio Code has released a new feature in April last year which enable to **organize imports** on save. Can you try to update your current `settings.json` with the following changes:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }
}
```

Hopefully this can be helpful and good luck!

Comment: is there a way to have it put an empty line between like-blocks? E.g., global imports, absolute path imports, relative imports all separate?

Comment: Does it work for commonJS imports as well? I mean for packages imported using `require` keyword.

Comment: Beautiful. I also added `"source.removeUnusedImports": true`.

Comment: looks like `true` [should now be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77637621/vscode-workspace-settings-change-on-its-own)  `"explicit"`:

Answer (score 49):

You can also use the following shortcut with your keyboard to "Organize imports":

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Is this for VS or VS Code?

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly VSC

Comment: Ok, thanks. The original question was for VS (not Code).

Answer (score 31):

A slightly modified version of JayKan's answer but this worked for me in VSCode settings.json.

```
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }
```

Comment: I think this must be accepted answer. Time saver answer.

Comment: Yes this is working for me too. Although I later switched it off as it was annoying me by deleting unused imports. Generally helpful, but a disaster when you are moving code between files, and thereby losing the relevant imports in the "old" file. Also a bit miserable when you bring a set of imports in from a template file and then try to write code that uses them. The ones you haven't used yet, keep disappearing.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2022 (might even be in previous releases too) the option `Organize Imports` in the editor's code context menu has been renamed to `Remove and Sort Usings`, which still does the same thing and also remains available using the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Just in case anyone overlooked it, as I did.

Comment: The shortcut wasn't set, go to preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts. I set mine to `cmd + shift + o` Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is a feature of Visual Studio **Code** and not Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: The Microsoft site says: "TypeScript’s language service now provides functionality to organize imports." So it should not be a feature of VS Code. Maybe it is not callable in VS 2017 yet.

Comment: BTW. I use Resharper for Visual Studio. It has Code Cleanup function with import organizing feature for Typescript. However not so good as VS Code

Comment: VS Code merges and sorts multiple imports from same source into one line. Visual Studio doesn't. 
VS Code adds new imports as you type more accurately. VIsual Studio sometimes does, somethimes doesn't.
Anycase, typescript in Visual Studio vs VS Code is a question of personal taste.

Comment: From version 15.8 onward Visual Studio 2017 now highlights unused imports by greying them out.