# VSCode workspace settings change on its own

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslintrc

I am using eslint, prettier, vite for a React project.

I have set my VSCode workspace settings for `"source.fixAll.eslint"` and `"source.organizeImports"` to `true`. But it keeps changing to `"explicit"` automatically, for example when I open VSCode or when I'm coding.

What might be the cause?

```json
// .vscode/settings.json (workspace settings)

{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true, // keeps automatically changing to "explicit"
    "source.organizeImports": true // keeps automatically changing to "explicit"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

```
// package.json devDependencies

"devDependencies": {
  "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
  "@types/jest": "^29.5.6",
  "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
  "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
  "eslint": "^8.45.0",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
  "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
  "husky": "^8.0.3",
  "jest": "^29.7.0",
  "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
  "lint-staged": "^15.0.2",
  "msw": "^1.3.2",
  "prettier": "^3.0.3",
  "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
  "typescript": "^5.0.2",
  "vite": "^4.4.5",
  "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.1"
},
```

```
// .eslintrc.cjs

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ["dist", ".eslintrc.cjs"],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  plugins: ["react-refresh", "eslint-plugin-react", "prettier"],
  rules: {
    "react-refresh/only-export-components": [
      "warn",
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
    "react/self-closing-comp": [
      "error",
      {
        component: true,
        html: true,
      },
    ],
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "no-console": "error",
  },
};
```

```json
// .prettierrc.json

{
  "singleQuote": false,
  "quoteProps": "consistent",
  "printWidth": 80,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "bracketSameLine": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "semi": true,
  "endOfLine": "auto",
  "eslintIntegration": false
}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Turns out, VSCode `true` is set to `"explicit"` since VSCode 1.85.0. It seems boolean values were supported until 1.84.0.

References

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_code-actions-on-save-and-auto
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_83#_code-actions-on-save-and-auto-save

Comment: This is very frustrating when vscode is changing a shared settings file that multiple people on the team are using, with different versions of vscode.

Comment: Agree. I guess for now it's best for the whole team to upgrade to 1.85.0 and set it to `"explicit"` once and for all as long as the upgrade doesn't affect other things in the project.

Comment: it still does support boolean

Comment: The 1.85.0 release mentions "The setting value updates are as follows, with the previous boolean values to be deprecated in favor of the string equivalent."